# Ubuntu Studio updated and now my mouse buttons don't work

Tags: mouse, gedit

I was trying Linux for the first time in 2021 (dual boot on two hard drives), found Ubuntu Studio, which seemed perfect for my music and graphics work. I never had the computer online until just recently. The distro updated and now my mouse buttons don't work. The cursor moves but the buttons don't do anything.

I don't know if it being wireless makes a difference. I found a video of a solution in terminal, that seemed to work for the guy in the video but mine doesn't get past:

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

It says " sudo: gedit: command not found "

It was working fine before and now I just want it back how it was without formatting and losing everything on there. A solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: The starting point I'd likely provide is what release you're using; as you didn't specify. Ubuntu Studio used to use Xfce (*older releases*) thus had `mousepad` as the text editor, however modern Ubuntu Studio uses KDE Plasma thus `kwrite` is the default editor.  `gedit` or a GNOME text editor isn't used by the desktops used by Ubuntu Studio.  I'll provide a 23.04 manifest showing what is installed by default (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/23.04/release/ubuntustudio-23.04-dvd-amd64.manifest as I don't know your release; other text editors may exist too, eg. I like `vim`)

Comment: Apologies for my late reply, I have been extremely busy. It was 21, I forget the month (I've cleared the data stick since, for other things), I'm guessing 04. You may have just solved it for me with " kwrite " (yes it was KDE Plasma) I'll try that a bit later. Thank you so much! I'll reply again if I run into problems later...

Comment: Any release from 2021 is now EOL (be it 21.04 or 21.10) and thus off-topic here. If you've had *release-upgraded* a 21.04 system it would have become 21.10; likewise 21.10 would have upgraded to 22.04 where you had a choice of remaining on LTS, or continuing to *release-upgrade* every 6-9 months. The release details matter (some have kernel stack choices! and switching stack can be a quick fix), but "updated" isn't clear unless we know release, how often you update (daily, weekly) to give a clue as to what was possibly upgraded; or you give specifics from logs.

Comment: Because I never had that computer online at all until just recent weeks, it had never updated. I just found a Facebook post from July 2021 wondering why I hadn't switched to Linux years ago, so it was obviously the 04 version.

Comment: *recent weeks* and *updates* makes little sense either; as Ubuntu 21.04 (*including all flavors like Ubuntu Studio*) reached EOL back in January 2022 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/) thus there have been no upgrades since then, and repositories were *moved* or *dropped* well more than a year ago. Getting your release details *clear* is a starting point & matters with Ubuntu Studio especially given DEsktop change; but a 2021 release won't have been updated if connected to internet in year+

Comment: If you were using a release from 2021; you'd have only received errors on attempts to upgrade due to the EOL status, and this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades guide will tell you how to deal with those; but you mention getting upgrades (not errors) so please check what you're running, as your details mark clear contradictions.

Comment: If you'd installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS however in 2021; you'd still get upgrades; however as it was the last release using Xfce desktop (*for Ubuntu Studio*), it has no *supported* upgrade path where breakage is not to be expected; being the end of the road except thru re-install, thus details matter. Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS is now EOL (https://ubuntustudio.org/2023/04/ubuntu-studio-20-04-has-reached-end-of-life/) though upgrades for base Ubuntu packages will still occur until 2025-April.